# Install Package in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to install bayespy on enthought canopy and have read through all the documentation and cannot figure it out. I import pip and then run the following code (I have tried many variations on this too) :

```
pip install <bayespy>
```

It keeps coming back with an error message. Do I need to specify the file path to bayespy possibly?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Edit :

```
pip install <bayespy>
  File "<ipython-input-2-bb1febf67aaf>", line 1
   pip install <bayespy>
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: do it at the command line, not inside python

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: so where is the command line? And it just comes back with an invalid syntax error message

Comment: adding to @jeremycg, remove the angle brackets before issuing the command

Comment: @MKaye What's the error message? That would help bypass a lot of speculation.

Comment: how do you access the command line, it looks to be something like canopy_cli?

Comment: The error is simpy SyntaxError

Comment: `command line` means `console/terminal` on Linux/Mac or `cmd.exe/powershell` on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic usage of "pip" is as a command-line tool.  Try this from the command prompt (NOT within a Python shell):

```
pip install bayespy
```

or perhaps

```
sudo pip install bayespy
```

Answer (score 0):

First: BayesPy requires Python 3.
Try This:

`yourMachine> sudo pip3 install bayespy`

Not this at python prompt: `>>> sudo pip3 install bayespy`

Comment: This doesn't work either and comes back with a SyntaxError, do I need to access the command line?

Comment: I am currently running in python

Comment: If BayesPy requires Python 3, you'd want to install it with `pip3`, not `pip`.

Comment: Oh I see, I have accessed the command prompt now, sorry for the dumbness...

Comment: I have tried above methods but says I need python 3, how do I install this (pip3 doesn't work @jwodder)

Comment: Python version 2.7.11

Comment: ok, You need to install python3 to use that package. I am going to stop here..... I dont want to give bad advice.. I use Linux and Mac, not Windows, and, stick with python 2 packages.  You may want to google how to run two versions of python on the same machine. but I dont it.. You may need to use    http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/, good luck.. Please upvote is this was helpful.